# /bin/sh: 1: /APP: Permission denied in Ubuntu Docker container

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y libpq-dev python3-dev python3-pip
ENTRYPOINT /APP
RUN mkdir -p /APP/OUTPUT
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3" "Main.py"]
```

But when i run the container, i get the following message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /APP: Permission denied in Ubuntu Docker container
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT /APP` says that `/APP` should be run as an application. It's not an application, it's a directory. It's not _expected_ that it should be successfully runnable as an application.

Comment: If you mean `/APP` is the directory that `python3 Main.py` and other subsequent commands should be run in, then you want `WORKDIR /APP`, not `ENTRYPOINT /APP`.

Comment: (`ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` get combined when you use them both, with the `CMD` becoming arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`)

Comment: i meant workdir, thanks

Comment: Indeed. With that fixed, do you still have a problem? (If not, I'd suggest deleting the question).